# What are some concepts I can look into to aide in creating a 'compression funnel'(?) without the aide of a motor?

Tags: vacuum, drag, aerodynamics, heat-engine

In short I'm designing a 'Humane fly swatter' for my University application into bachelor of Industrial Design.

The idea is to utilise the energy of swatting a fly to capture air through an intake, compress it and ejecting it at a higher velocity in turn drawing more air through the intake creating a slight vacuum, enough to draw the fly into a holding container.

To reiterate I'm not looking to create a big suction from the intake itself. Think of the swatter more as a butterfly net. You are capturing the fly into the funnel and from within the funnel the air velocity would have increased enough to suck the fly the remainder of the way into the holding container.

Simple visualisation of air being compressed and ejected through a formed funnel. 
[image: Essentially this effect]

So I'm wondering if anyone could at the bare minimum provide me with some keywords and concepts that I can use to help me research ways of achieving this and to use this information to inform my concept designs. My biggest issues isn't understanding the concepts but not having to vocabulary to be able to search for what I need.

Thanks

Comment: This is far more an engineeringSE question, imo.

Comment: noted. I'll see how this goes and will repost in the morning.

Comment: You probably know this, but maybe keywords would include venturi tube, ducted fan, rocket nozzle, hand powered sprayer. I think what you are looking for is along the lines of a badminton shuttlecock.   Also if you do search for these words, press the images search button as well. Best of luck with it.  Don't expect to get a word of thanks from the flies though.